# Is there a way to create a centralized log system for .Net Framework API with multiple controllers?

Tags: .net, logging

I have an API and it has 5 controller. It is using by mobile application.
I want to create a log system for which user is using which service.

Firstly, I though it can be done by creating a log function and call it in all related functions. However if I do that, I need to call it all future functions and sometimes I can forget to add it. Also its code repeating.

Is there any option in .Net Framework like middlewares, so I can handle all request in common point and call log function just one time in that?